# Do I have to backup .trn files even if I backup log file

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a maintenance plan to our database because nobody has make it since their creation. I have been reading about full backups, differentials etc but I am really confused with the `.trn` files. I had to stop a task that created this files because they were not being deleted never so it grow to more than a million of files. I have also read about backup the log file if you have a full recovery mode.

My question is if I backup the DatabaseName_log file frequently do I have to backup also the `.trn` files?

Comment: @kp; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a big No, if you have a maintenance plan to take differential and full backup there is no need to keep any other file.